# "Webhooks failing" and "webhooks disabled" error while trying to set up facebook messenger bot

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, heroku, bots, chatbot

I'm trying to setup a Facebook messenger bot and keep running into the same two errors.

Webhooks failing:

[image: Webhooks failing]

Webhooks disabled:

[image: Webhooks disabled]

I'm creating my chatbot with NodeJS, Express, and a server. I am running my webhook on a heroku server. I have had it verified and saved by Facebook.

After that, I ran this code:

```
curl -ik -X POST "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/subscribed_apps?access_token=<token>"
```

this replied with a success message so I started adding code to reply to the incoming messages but I can't seem to get it connected.

Here is my code:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// body parser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  if (req.query['hub.verify_token'] === '<myToken>') {
    res.send(req.query['hub.challenge']);
  }
  res.send('Error, wrong validation token');
})

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
  messaging_events = req.body.entry[0].messaging;
  for (i = 0; i < messaging_events.length; i++) {
    event = req.body.entry[0].messaging[i];
    sender = event.sender.id;
    if (event.message && event.message.text) {
      text = event.message.text;
      sendTextMessage(sender, "Text received, echo: "+ text.substring(0, 200));
    }
  }
  res.sendStatus(200);
});

// error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  console.error(err.stack);
  res.status(400).send(err.message);
});

app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Listening on port ' + port);
});

var token = <myToken>;

function sendTextMessage(sender, text) {
  messageData = {
    text:text
  }
  request({
    url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages',
    qs: {access_token:token},
    method: 'POST',
    json: {
      recipient: {id:sender},
      message: messageData,
    }
  }, function(error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
      console.log('Error sending message: ', error);
    } else if (response.body.error) {
      console.log('Error: ', response.body.error);
    }
  });
}
```

At this point I should be able to start a chat with my bot and have it reply with an echo but nothing is happening.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are not listening on the correct endpoint.
Your `app.post('/'` should be

```
    app.post('/webhook', function(req, res) {
    var messagingEvents = req.body.entry[0].messaging;

    messagingEvents.forEach(function(event) {
    var sender = event.sender.id;
```

Comment: Would I change the _app.get_ function also?

Comment: Yes...they should both be listening on the webhook endpoint.  Both get & post

Comment: Ok, am I using the wrong webhook? When I try to run this `app.get('/wyrdbot.herokuapp.com', function (req, res) {` I get a _Cannot Get /_ Error when I load my webhook in my browser.

Comment: Try replacing '/wyrdbot.herokuapp.com' with '/webhook'